# Graphic image rendering corrupted

Tags: graphics, fonts, radeon, desktop-background, vga

I'm using lubuntu 18.04 and I keep it up to date to avoid problems.
However, latelly I wanted to enable the Radeon graphic card to off-load the CPU, but enabling it results in a corrupted image as shown below.
[image]
[Link to corrupted screen image](https://postimg.cc/cvztKRFX)

I tried several parameters and settings of the radeon driver to avoid this corruption without any luck. One of the effects is that if I over the pointer onto the defects, they disappear for a few seconds and then they reappear again in other positions.

```
agpmode  4
...
disp_priority  0 , 1 , 2
..
dynclks  -1 , 0 , 1
fastfb  0 , 1
...
modeset  1
...
no_wb  0 , 1
...
```

The only way I observed the corruption disappear is when I **remove** memory below 1GB of total size. By the way, I did swap around the modules to check if one is defective, but no, all of them seam to be fine as long as the total memory remains below the 1GB.

Here is some characteristics of the laptop I'm using:

```
user@bcn-lap:~$ sudo lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82855PM Processor to I/O Controller (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82855PM Processor to AGP Controller (rev 03)
...
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 81)
...
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller (rev 01)
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV250/M9 GL [Mobility FireGL 9000/Radeon 9000] (rev 01)
...
```

Any pointer of how to avoid this rendering problem is much appreciated.